# How to create a dataframe in which one column's input is dynamic and derived via an IF statement dependent on another entry in that column

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, numpy, if-statement

I am looking to convert a two column Excel table which uses IF statements to calculate values in the second column, in to a Pandas dataframe.

[image]

Column A figures are static.

Column B figures are dynamic (with the exception of B5 which always remains 100%) and are calculated in Excel with the following IF statement (row 5 being the starting/reference point):

B4 =IF((B5*(1+Variable_1))<2, B5*(1+Variable_1), 2)

B3 =IF((B4*(1+Variable_1))<2, B4*(1+Variable_1), 2)

B2 =IF((B3*(1+Variable_1))<2, B3*(1+Variable_1), 2)

...and so on.

Variable_1 = a percentage (in this example 5%) which used when column A is negative.

When column A switches to positive i.e. >0% (A5), the IF statement changes to:

B6 =IF((B5*(1-Variable_2))>0, B5*(1-Variable_2), 0)

B7 =IF((B6*(1-Variable_2))>0, B6*(1-Variable_2), 0)

… and so on.

Variable_2 is also a percentage and is used when column B is positive (in this example it is also 5%).

I'm a complete amateur when it comes to Python but im hoping someone out there can assist me with something which is rather easy to do in Excel!
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: why need it dynamic? just create a df with the values from above?

Comment: Hi Patrick, it has to be dynamic otherwise I would have just done what you said.

Comment: to what purpose? If you change something in A, B wont be recalculated. Pandas stores values - not calculations. It is not like in excel where you change something in A and the df autocalculates B

Comment: Thanks Patrick. What you described i.e. changes to A and the df autocalculates B, is exactly what I am looking to do.

Comment: Variable_1 and variable_2 will change and I then want the table in the OP to update to reflect this.

Comment: Presumably the table would just need to be updated as and when the variables change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, then you can reconstruct your dataframe every time you want A to change:

```
A = [i/100.0 for i in range(-4,5)]

v1 = 5/100.0
v2 = 5/100.0

b5 = 1.0
b4 = min(2,b5*(1+v1))
b3 = min(2,b4*(1+v1))
b2 = min(2,b3*(1+v1))
b1 = min(2,b2*(1+v1))

b6 = max(0,b5*(1-v2))
b7 = max(0,b6*(1-v2))
b8 = max(0,b7*(1-v2))
b9 = max(0,b8*(1-v2))


import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {"A": A, "B": [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9]})

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      A         B
0 -0.04  1.215506
1 -0.03  1.157625
2 -0.02  1.102500
3 -0.01  1.050000
4  0.00  1.000000
5  0.01  0.950000
6  0.02  0.902500
7  0.03  0.857375
8  0.04  0.814506
```

Comment: Patrick, you're a gent. You have nailed it. This is exactly what I was looking to achieve. In my early foray in to the world I really appreciate the different ways of approaching problems. Really appreciate your help on this. Thank you.